# Laravel: route() возвращает ссылку на API, ожидаю ссылку на web-версию

Tags: laravel

В шаблоне используется

```
route("company.index")
```

который превращался в `/company`. После добавления роутов для API, ссылка поменялась на `/api/company`, хотя я все также ожидаю ссылку `/company`.

`RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    });
}
```

`web.php`:

```
Route::middleware("auth")->group(function () {
    Route::resource("/company", \App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController::class);
});
```

`api.php`:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::apiResource("/company", \App\Http\Controllers\CompanyControllerApi::class);
});
```

Как можно разграничить эти два вида роутов, чтобы `route("company.index")` и подобные всегда вели на web-версию (не API). Либо "отключить" генерацию для API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте первым параметром `['as' => 'api.']` в `group`.

```
Route::group(
    [
        'middleware' => ['auth:api'],
        'as' => 'api.'
    ],
    function () {
        Route::apiResource("/company", \App\Http\Controllers\CompanyControllerApi::class);
    }
);
```

Для **web** будет `route("company.index")`, **api** `route("api.company.index")`.